# How can i read JSON syntax diagram?

Tags: python, json

I have got lessons about JSON, but i forgot how i could read a JSON syntax diagram. 
I have searched on internet and couldn't find an explanation about it.

[image: JSON Syntax diagram]

For example, i have number 15 how can i read this? Because the number isn't 0, i go to minus and 15-1 = 14 but from here i dont know what to do because the number 14 isn't a digit from 1 - 9, so do i need to go back to the loop where i subtract the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: path through diagram]

The number `15` is, from left to right:

- *not* `-`, so you skip that
- then it's a digit `1-9`
- then it's more such digits
- then it's *not* `.`, so you skip that branch
- then it's *not* `e` or `E`, so you skip that branch
- done

Comment: Thank you very much, i understand it now.